# Does not working solid icon which is only available in solid for Photoshop

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am using font awesome latest Version 5.1.1. Does not work solid icon in Photoshop. I have realized. **Does solid icon working which is available in Regular & solid. Does not working solid icon which is only available in solid for Photoshop.**

have you face any this type issue?

I have install on desktop.

- Font Awesome 5 Brands-Regular-400.otf
- Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf
- Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed totally Font awesome fonts from desktop. and also, have closed Photoshop. & then again has Install Font awesome Icon. So, It is working now.